# interfacing with Forge Viewer from thirdparty application

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I have a thirdparty Apex based application . How could I open a revit file and pass few revit element Ids as parameters to forge viewer and highlight the elements. Is it possible. I did several addins on revit using csharp.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Apex, and I don't think Forge Viewer has any component or wrapper for this platform. But the viewer can simply be interacted with using its [JavaScript APIs](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/Viewing/Viewer3D) (for example, you can load a model into the viewer using the `viewer.loadDocumentNode` method, or select one or more design elements using the `viewer.select` method), so if Apex allows you to insert custom HTML elements into your app, and interact with them using vanilla JavaScript, this might be doable.

I'd suggest that you take a look at one of the basic tutorials in [Learn Forge](https://learnforge.autodesk.io) to understand how the viewer is typically initialized and inserted into the HTML (using a little bit of JavaScript), and see if something similar could be done from your Apex application.